# Need help understanding an SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL, Employee_Details, having three columns, Name, Age and Salary. I came across this query to select the highest salary from the table which goes like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee_Details e 
WHERE 0 = (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT Salary) 
   FROM Employee_Details 
   WHERE Salary > e.Salary
)
```

I have no idea about what the '0' signifies. Could anyone please give me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a condition that says that the count from the `Employee_Details` table in the inner `SELECT` query must be 0 (no one can have a higher salary than the Employee selected in the outer `SELECT`)

The approach to do it this way seems a bit odd to me..... I would probably have used something like this:

```
SELECT (columns) 
FROM dbo.Employee_Details e 
WHERE e.Salary = (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM dbo.Employee_Details)
```

which should produce the same result - only it seems a lot clearer to me what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Get all from table Employee_details where count of salary is 0

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be written as `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM Employee_Details e ORDER BY Salary DESC` (in T-SQL dialect). Condition in original query checks if the number of distinct values of Salary greater than `Salary` value in `e` is zero (i.e. there are no rows with greater `Salary`).

Comment: I still am not able to understand the logic behind it. How does it retrieve the highest Salary? Please help me understand the logic involved.

Comment: For each row in `Employee_Details` whole table is scanned again, but this time only rows with `Salary` higher than outer row are counted. If the result of this count is zero, outer row is selected. Subquery will return 0 if and only if there is no row in `Employee_Details` with greater Salary - which by definition - means maximum row.